# C# Console Import Excel to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, excel, import, console

I have [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-SqlBulkCopy-to-import-Excel-SpreadSheet-data-into-SQL-Server-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) reference in importing excel data to SQL using C#. But I want this to be a Console Program.

Please help me how to.

Thank you.

Code:

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{
    //Upload and save the file
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

```
string conString = string.Empty;
string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
switch (extension)
{
    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
        break;
    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
        break;

}
conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    excel_con.Open();
    string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

    //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
    dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
    {
        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
    }
    excel_con.Close();

    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            //Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPersons";

            //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");
            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static void LoadExcelMain()
{
    //Upload and save the file
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(excelPath); 
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;

    }
    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

        //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
        }
        excel_con.Close();

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPersons";

                //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadExcelMain();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED V2**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class CS
{
    static void LoadExcelMain(string excelPath)
    {

        string conString = string.Empty;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(excelPath);
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\sample.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES';"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\sample.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"].ConnectionString;
                break;

        }
        conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            //read sheet named TABLE_NAME from excell , with columns : Name , Salary
            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

            //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }
            excel_con.Close();

            string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=10.90.76.187\\ServDB;Initial Catalog=TestDB;user id=DBUserID;password=@pps_st@61ng;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    //load in table named "dbo.employee" with columns: Id ,Name, Salary
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "testdb.dbo.employee";

                    //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");
                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadExcelMain("C:\\sample.xlsx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats stopping it from being a console app?

Comment: @BugFinder because an error  "The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace" occurs. And I believe it is because it is originally ASP app

Comment: Ok, but theres no mention of a "UI" in your code here, so clearly that issue doesnt lie in the code you've provided but somewhere else..

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions, especially examples about good and bad titles: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - further please add the error that occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

is used in case GUI 
For console , rename it to e.g.

```
static void LoadExcelMain()
    {
      your code here
    }
```

Call the method in :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  LoadExcelMain();
}
```

you need to modify methods used in web application to get file extension

```
//modify :
string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
//to be
string extension = Path.GetExtension(excelPath);    

//You need to add entry in App.Config for the connectionString

//You can't to use = Server.MapPath in console application
//Review carefully the mapping of columns in the table in the csv file
```

**Edit:**

**Here is your post code modified to remove syntax errors**

Try it , with modifying table_name , table structure, connectionstring

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class CS
```

{

```
// loading excel file into sql server 

static void LoadExcelMain(string excelPath)
{

    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(excelPath);
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;

    }
    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        //read sheet named TABLE_NAME from excell , with columns : Name , Salary
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

        //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
        }
        excel_con.Close();

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                //load in table named "dbo.tblPersons" with columns: Id ,Name, Salary
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPersons";

                //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    LoadExcelMain("myfile.xls");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining and understanding that I am a newbie. Will modify current codes with this and give you an update

Comment: Welcome. comment for any problems you face.

Comment: I took effect those in my codes and remove all UI-related but getting problems still.

Comment: Please take a look on the updated codes. I brought back what I did remove but I left your given codes

Comment: You are the greatest, it is now a console program indeed. Thank you very much. Can you still help me with the configuration? because I'm getting error with the connection strings, I don't know if I did it right. Please take a look on the update.

Comment: Anyways, thank you very much. Have a good day :)

Comment: i modified  your code in OP

Comment: OMG! It is working fine now. I just can't thank you enough. You're amazing!